# ReactJS: Uncaught TypeError: this.props. is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two react-components. Parent component has a function `handleOnChangeTaskCategory` which is used like props in child component.
Parent component:

```js
export default class TodoList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        this.handleOnChangeTaskCategory = this.handleOnChangeTaskCategory.bind(this);
    }

    handleOnChangeTaskCategory(taskList) {//
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
                <div className="row">{
                    this.state.toDoList.map(taskList => {
                        return <TaskGroup onEditTaskCategory={this.handleOnEditTaskCategory} />
                    })
                }
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And children component:

```js
export default class TaskGroup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.handleOnAddTask = this.handleOnAddTask.bind(this);
    }
    handleOnAddTask() {
        this.props.onEditTaskCategory(update(this.props.listOfTasks, {
            tasks: {
                $push: newTask
            }
        }));
    }
    
    render() {
        return (   
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.handleOnAddTask}>Add task</a>
        );
    }
}
```

But when I click "Add task", I have an error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onEditTaskCategory is not a function
> at TaskGroup.handleOnAddTask

Comment: Try doing `super()` before you bind your method

Comment: i think typo in parent: `onEditTaskCategory={this.handleOnEditTaskCategory}` should be `onEditTaskCategory={this.handleOnChangeTaskCategory}`

Comment: try adding super(props) in the children component like this 
```constructor(props) {
super(props)//ADD THIS
        this.handleOnAddTask = this.handleOnAddTask.bind(this);
    }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class method -> handleOnChangeTaskCategory
method passed to component property -> handleOnEditTaskCategory`

you have typo there